# Como mudar a opacidade de uma parte da imagem?

Tags: javascript, css

Estou mapeando uma imagem para que quando eu clicar em determinada área, outra página seja referenciada em um iframe. Entretanto, para que o usuário possa saber onde está clicando, eu quero aumentar a opacidade daquela área e colocar um texto.

```
<img src="..." usemap="#mapa"/>
<map name="mapa">
    <span id="tutorias">
        <area shape="rect" coords="" href="teste1.html" target="janela">
        <p>Tutorias</p>
    </span>
    <area shape="rect" coords="" href="teste2.html" target="janela">
</map>
```

Bem, minha idéia era de mostrar um texto em cima das coordenadas passadas. De forma que que só cobrisse aquela determinada área.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resumindo o que eu planejo, é mostrar o nome da área que o usuário colocar o mouse e demarca-la.

Comment: Coloque o código que você já tem para que possamos ver a situação.

Comment: Ele colocou Rafael, assim como exemplo rodando e funcionando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez esse código sem o uso de `javascript` possa lhe ajudar. Para fazer o mapeamento da imagem  você pode usar qualquer editor de imagem para pegar as coordenadas. Esse código usa apenas `HTML` e `CSS`.Não coloquei o efeito de opacidade.Apenas um  `tooltip`.Eu mapeei apenas as duas primeiras cores da imagem(preto,verde) Espero ter ajudado!

```css
a.tooltip {outline:none; }
a.tooltip strong {line-height:30px;}
a.tooltip:hover {text-decoration:none;} 
a.tooltip span {
    z-index:10;display:none; padding:14px 20px;
    margin-top:-30px; margin-left:28px;
    width:300px; line-height:16px;
}
a.tooltip:hover span{
    display:inline; position:absolute; color:#111;/*cor da fonte*/
    border:1px solid #DCA; background:#fffAF0;}/*fundo  do tooltip quando o mouse passa por cima*/
.callout {z-index:20;position:absolute;top:30px;border:0;left:-12px;}
    
/*Borda sombreada do tooltip*/
a.tooltip span
{
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #CCC;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/n5CHkgjdJBSy1_HAv7jqa9fly-ouHgnEVsHBs4mRf0ibAwQZKyRuPDsot_Tj3ghuZlqs=s170" height="66" width="256"
             usemap="#meumapa"/>
 <map name="meumapa">
<a href="#" class="tooltip" >
  <area shape="rect" coords="3,4,62,61" href="#"  /><span>
        <strong>Cor negra</strong><br/>
        Assim você pode mapear sua imagem e colocar
  o testo que desejar.
    </span></a> 
<a href="#" class="tooltip"> 
  <area shape="rect" coords="65,3,124,62" href="#" /><span><strong>Cor Verde</strong><br/>
        Realmente muito fácil e sem o uso de javascript.
    </span></a>

 </map>
```

Comment: Era quase isso que eu imaginava @PenaPintada, mas se ficar legal aqui eu aceitarei esta solução.

Comment: Essa resposta pra mim ficou boa, @PenaPintada, muito obrigado! Você se incomodaria de comentar as linhas desse código CSS e enviar-me por email pra que eu possa entender o funcionamento e depois adaptar?

Comment: Agora que notei que tem um probleminha. As mensagens aparecem sempre abaixo uma da outra e não no mesmo local.

Comment: @MarceloAugusto Você fez exatamente como no exemplo?

Comment: Fiz sim, os mesmos códigos

Comment: Sei sim, @PenaPintada. Tô separando por salas.Por exemplo, na imagem que coloquei, terei 7 áreas.

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer o que pertende pode usar javascript então eu sugiro os seguintes exemplos

[escrever usando javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_myfirst)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h1>My First JavaScript</h1>

    <button type="button"
    onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
    Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

[mudando a opacidade em javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_opacity)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#myDIV {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#DIV2 {
    position: relative;
    top: 130px;
    left: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: coral;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to see through the blue DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="DIV2">
  <h1>Voila!</h1>
</div>

<div id="myDIV">
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {


           document.getElementById("myDIV").style.opacity = "0.5";
   }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok coloquei os exemplos